# textbox is not displaying some text in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to display some amount of text in ScrollableTextBlock but only some part of the text is displayed remaining part is not displayed since i have huge data i think its not displaying how to overcome this limitation.

When small amount of data is added its displayed but if there is a huge amount of data some data is truncated.

Here is the code which i have implemented so far. It displays only for less data, when there is huge data to be displayed on ScrollableTextBlock, it doesn't display.

```
my:ScrollableTextBlock Text="ScrollableTextBlockcfbvc"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="scrollableTextBlock1"
VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="500" Width="427" Margin="12,6,0,0" />
```

Comment: can you post code of..ScrollableTextBlock usercontrol..

Answer (score 0):

Try TextWrapping Property which may resize your TextBlock according the amount of data given.